# Unable to convert epoch time to standard time in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am unable to convert the following epoch time '-28800000' to standard time in MySQL.
I used this [online_epoch_converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to check for the value and had the following results:

GMT: Saturday, February 1, 1969 4:00:00 PM

Your time zone: Sunday, February 2, 1969 12:00:00 AM GMT+08:00

I checked and found that the valid range in mysql is from 1970 to 2038.

I checked the timezone setting of mysql and returned a value of 'SYSTEM'.

I then checked the system timezone which is Singapore Standard Time.

Can someone please help? Many thanks!

EDITED:

I have some other records in my table that returns the desired converted value perfectly. So I am checking for options that could eliminate the issue but also maintain the ones that are running fine.

Had tried three scripts for these as follows:

a. FROM_UNIXTIME((SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB('1969-12-31 16:00:00', INTERVAL 1 SECOND)) + (-28800000/1000)), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'

- this returns **NULL**

b. DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME((SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB('1969-12-31 16:00:00', INTERVAL 1 SECOND)) + (-28800000/1000)), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')

- this returns **NULL**

c.DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('1970-01-01', INTERVAL -28800000/1000 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')

- this returns **1969-12-31T16:00:00Z**

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your timestamp is in seconds. so no need to divide it by 1000.

```
select DATE_ADD('1970-01-01', INTERVAL -28800000 SECOND);
```

Result :

```
`1969-02-01 16:00:00`
```

You can convert it to your local time using `DATE_FORMAT()`